# How do I run Gnome from a systemd-nspawn container in a second X server?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, systemd, chroot

I'm using systemd-nspawn to "boot" a second Linux OS from a USB hard disk. I'd like to launch that OS's Gnome Desktop in a second X server running on the same machine on a different tty than the Desktop that is already running on tty1.

e.g. I have Gnome on tty1 running on the host machine. I'd like to launch the USB drive's KDE desktop in tty2 (in a 2nd X server I'm assuming). It seems possible somehow.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but not easy...

First, you have to bind mount tty2 and modules, so spawn the container using:

```
# assuming you have your system in the /system/arch dir
systemd-nspawn -bD /system/arch --bind /dev/tty2 --bind /lib/modules
```

Then, as asumed by the command, spawn the container in tty2 terminal.
You also need to start an X-server in another tty:

```
startx -display :1 -- :1 vt2 &
```

The best option is to just freeze one xserver instance and start another in tty2, as both running would conflict and would waste resources.

P.S.: There is also a guy that ran a container's program under host's xserver, here http://dabase.com/e/12009/